# navbar-fixed-top show content behind Navbar

Tags: react-bootstrap

How do you prevent the content from floating behind the Navbar when scrolling?

```
<Navbar className="navbar-form navbar-fixed-top" responsive collapseable brand='x' inverse toggleNavKey={1} onClick={this.handleMouseDown}>
```

Or is it in:

```
<Nav className="navigation"..
```

Thanks

Answer (score 15):

Add a custom class to your `navbar` component, say, `sticky-nav`. Define the following CSS properties on it:

```
.sticky-nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

This will make your navbar stick to the top and will automatically adjust the height of its following DOM elements. You can read more about the `sticky` property on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Comment: That worked for me! also adding a z-index property would be useful, in case some elements scroll above the header.

Comment: This fixed by navbar even after scrolling. But when I scroll, the images are overlapping on the navbar. Is there a solution to that problem?

Comment: @akshayagashe look up the z-index CSS property.

Answer (score 6):

As [Scrotch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3728233/scrotch) said adding:

```
<Navbar style={{backgroundColor: "#071740", position: "sticky"}} variant="dark" fixed="top">
```

worked for me, I did it inline but putting in a separate CSS file should work as well. This is the only thing that's worked so far for me.

NB: I'm using `"react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.16"`

Comment: Adding just fixed="top" to the Navbar did the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

I was running into this too.  I found the following (baseline bootstrap) [page](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/) that shows a fixed navbar and has the main page showing up properly below it.  It seems to be a function of the [css](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/navbar-fixed-top.css) that they are using.  Specifically:

```
padding-top: 70px;
```

I added

```
body {
    padding-top: 70px;
}
```

to my css file, and it seems to be working.  Obviously mileage may vary, not applicable in all territories, etc.  I am going to need to test it further for myself, but that might get you started.

Comment: This is nice as long as you don't need responsiveness. For responsive design you have to determine Navbar height dynamically and adjust `padding-top` according to current Navbar height value.

Comment: I think handling this in CSS with media queries is cleaner than adding logic to react code IMHO

Comment: @Manuel Hernandez finally someone points in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get responsive padding-top for body you may use sth. like this (ES6 example):

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class Template extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { navHeight: 50 };

    this.handleResize = this.handleResize.bind(this);
  }

  handleResize(e = null) {
    this.setState({ navHeight: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this._navbar).offsetHeight });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
    this.handleResize();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <body style={{paddingTop: this.state.navHeight}}>
        <Navbar ref={(e) => this._navbar = e} fixedTop>
          <Navbar.Header>
            <Navbar.Brand>
              <Link to="/">Some title</Link>
            </Navbar.Brand>
          </Navbar.Header>
          <Nav>
            <NavItem eventKey={1} href="/link1">Link1</NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey={2} href="/link2">Link2</NavItem>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar>
        <main>
          {this.props.children}
        </main>
      </body>
    );
  }
}

Template.propTypes = {
  navHeight: React.PropTypes.number,
  children: React.PropTypes.object,
};
```

This way your `<body>` padding-top will always fit your navbar height even after adding more links in mobile view.
I also assume that base height is **50px** (see the constructor) but it shouldn't matter as long as you call `this.handleResize()` in `componentDidMount()`.

Answer (score 2):

There is also the option to specify `sticky-top` which basically implements the solution of using `position:sticky` that others have suggested ([see documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#placement)).

So in your example you could just specify `sticky-top` instead of `fixed-top` as a className, and it satisfies your requirements.

Comment: This is the best answer here. React Bootstrap docs: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/#navbars-placement

Answer (score 2):

react-bootstrap provides position utilities.

```
<Navbar sticky="top">
```

[react-bootstrap documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/#placement)

However in-page anchor does not work properly, and position can be under the navbar after jump from a link.

I also use this custom css to fix the issue.

```
*[id]:before { 
  display: block; 
  content: " "; 
  margin-top: -75px; 
  height: 75px; 
  visibility: hidden; 
}
```

[Reference](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/1768#issuecomment-46519033)

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem. Wanting to stay within bootstrap and avoid custom css I tried adding class 'position-sticky', which gave me a left-shifted navbar. Apparently, for whatever reason, the navbar has a negative padding, so adding 'ps-0' to the class list fixed it.

```
<Navbar 
    fixed={'top'}
    className={'position-sticky ps-0'}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

for anyone using tailwind use sticky as a property in the top div of your navbar

```
<div className="sticky"> navbar-content </div>
```