# How to link 2 components in React and in a new page still have a navigation bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation, components

I have built a website to React. My code is here https://codesandbox.io/s/3d-tool-zjm5m?file=/src/components/modeling.jsx. What I want is when the user clicks on the button "Go upload" in Modeling tab, it will link to a new page of upload.jsx with still have the navigation bar.

App.js code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Navigation from './components/navigation';
import Header from './components/header';
import About from './components/about';
import Modeling from './components/modeling';
import Resources from './components/resources';
import Team from './components/Team';
import JsonData from './data/data.json';

export class App extends Component {
  state = {
    landingPageData: {},
  }
  getlandingPageData() {
    this.setState({landingPageData : JsonData})
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getlandingPageData();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navigation />
        <Header data={this.state.landingPageData.Header} />
        <About data={this.state.landingPageData.About} />
        <Modeling data={this.state.landingPageData.Modeling} />
        <Resources data={this.state.landingPageData.Resources} /> 
        <Team data={this.state.landingPageData.Team} />
    
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Modeling.jsx code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Upload from "./upload";

export class Modeling extends Component {
  uploadButton = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.history.push({
      pathname: "/upload"
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="modeling">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="about-text">
              <h2>3D MODELING</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className=" wow fadeInUp slow">
            <div className="row pt-5 justify-content-center">
              <div className="col text-center">
                <h1>
                  <b>Pick what's right for you </b>
                </h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row p-5 p-md-0 pt-md-5 justify-content-around">
            <div
              class="col-md-5 mb-4 m-md-0 ml-md-5 modern-card card card-body shadow text-center wow fadeIn slow"
              data-wow-delay="0.2s"
            >
              <h2 class="mb-3 blue">
                <b>A 3D model from a 2D image.</b>
              </h2>

              <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-primary go-button"
                onclick={this.uploadButton}
              >
                Go upload
              </button>
            </div>

            <div
              class="col-md-5 mr-md-5 modern-card card card-body shadow text-center wow fadeIn slow"
              data-wow-delay="0.4s"
            >
              <h2 class="mb-3 blue">
                <b>A virtual tour from a 3D model.</b>
              </h2>

              <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-primary go-button"
                
              >
                Go!
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Modeling;

Can someone stop by give me any suggestions? I have really appreciated it. Thanks!
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code. Can you update and share your routing/navigation component code so that we may see how you are rendering/matching routes?

Comment: NM, I see now that your app *isn't* using any navigation/routing package. It seems you are wanting to do a `history.push` to the new route. [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) is a good solution (IMHO). TL;DR, wrap your app in a `Router` and each "page" in a `Route`. Use the passed `history` route prop to imperatively navigate. If you try this out and get stuck we can help.

Comment: Do you mean I change everything in App.js into router? Like <Route path="/modeling" component={Modeling} />

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/3d-tool-zjm5m?file=/src/App.js I just make some change for the route of each "Page". However, the button "Go upload" in Modeling tab does not link to Upload.jsx. Could you give me some help?

Comment: @DrewReese can you give me some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your navigation bar has hashlinks to sections on what amounts to a "homepage". When you introduce app navigation and want more than a single page then you should use `Link` components versus anchor tags. You also need to place the `Navigation` component on a route so it has access to the `Router` context.

#### App.js

Since you already wrap the *entire* app in a `Router` you need only place the `Navigation` and "homepage" components in `Route`s. Render the "homepage" components into an anonymous component and remember to pass the route props through to each component.

```
<div>
  <Route component={Navigation} />
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/upload" component={Upload} />
    <Route
      render={(routeProps) => (
        <>
          <Header {...routeProps} data={this.state.landingPageData.Header} />
          <About {...routeProps} data={this.state.landingPageData.About} />
          <Modeling {...routeProps} data={this.state.landingPageData.Modeling} />
          <Resources {...routeProps} data={this.state.landingPageData.Resources} />
          <Team {...routeProps} data={this.state.landingPageData.Team} />
        </>
      )}
    />
  </Switch>
</div>
```

#### Navigation.jsx

In order to keep the hashlink functionality working, and from other pages you will need to also import a `HashLink` component.

```
import { HashLink } from "react-router-hash-link";
```

And change all the anchor tags to `HashLink` components.

```
<HashLink className="navbar-brand page-scroll" to="/#page-top">
  3D RECONSTRUCTION TOOL
</HashLink>{" "}

...

<HashLink to="/#page-top" className="page-scroll">
  Home
</HashLink>
// ...etc...
```

#### Modeling.jsx

Fix the button's `onClick` prop, it is `onClick` not `onclick`. Because route props were passed in from `App.js`, the `history` prop is now available for the imperative navigation.

```
uploadButton = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.props.history.push({
    pathname: "/upload"
  });
};

...

<button
  type="button"
  className="btn btn-primary go-button"
  onClick={this.uploadButton}
>
  Go upload
</button>
```

Now you may notice when navigating to the new page on "/upload" that the navigation header is still fixed to the top of the window and the page is rendered underneath. This is style being applied from `react-bootstrap`. To resolve this you can add `padding-top` to the body to push content down under the header.

```
body {
  padding-top: /* whatever the navigation header height is */;
}
```

Your header is dynamic though, depending on view width, so you will likely need to check the view width and set this in JS. Here's a promising solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38105035/8690857

Comment: thanks for your answer, it does help me a lot. One more thing, could you help me in the home page, why when I clicked the Modeling tab, it looks like the Modeling page is rendered underneath?

Comment: @Sunny That is the last bit of my answer. It is because the react-bootstrap CSS and the navigation header being fixed to the top of the window, page content also starts from the top of the page but it's under the header. You can add `padding-top` to the body to push the content down, but because the header height is dynamic you may need to do this in JS. I also linked to another SO question dealing with exactly this issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I am really appreciated for that